# How do I add a third variable to a jQuery "each" function?

Tags: jquery, function

I've got a bit of a tricky issue. I'm trying to add a *third* parameter to the following function/loop and have hit a wall. Help?

```
$.each(studentselectValues, function(key, value) {   
    $('select[name="cf_Student"]')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value",key)
        .text(value)); 
});
```

Here's what the code looks like for the `studentselectValues` variable:

```
studentselectValues = {
    '1': 'My 1st Option',
    '2': 'My 2nd Option',
    '3': 'My 3rd Option'
}
```

What I'm doing is populating a select with the options shown above. My goal is to add a *third* attribute to each select. Does anyone have a clue how I would accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd make the `studentselectValues` hash into an array of hashes ... that way you can use as many attributes as you need:

```
studentselectValues = [
    { id: '1', key: 'My 1st Option', text: 'First' },
    { id: '2', key: 'My 2nd Option', text: 'Second' },
];

$.each(studentselectValues, function(index, item) {   
    $('select[name="cf_Student"]')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value",item.key)
        .text(item.text)); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/866z6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to make a array with objects, then are you possible to feed it with what you want.

```
   var studentselectValues = [
     { value: 1, label: 'test', extraattr: 'hoho' },
     { value: 2, label: 'test2', extraattr: 'test' }
   ];

  $.each(studentselectValues, function() {   
    $('select[name="cf_Student"]')
        .append($("<option/>")
        .val(this.value)
        .attr('data-id', this.extraattr)
        .text(this.label));
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
studentselectValues = [{
    {key:'1', value:'My 1st Option', third:"third value"},
    {key:'2', value:'My 2nd Option', third:"third value"},
    {key:'3', value:'My 3rd Option', third:"third value"}
}];

$.each(studentselectValues, function(index, data) {
$('select[name="cf_Student"]')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value",data.key)
        .text(data.value+ " "+ data.third)); 
}
```

On a sidenote, you shouldn't append each item in the loop: it's resource-heavy. Concatenate and then append instead.

```
var studentselectValues = [{
    value: '1',
    key: 'test',
    third: 'hoho'
}, {
    value: '2',
    key: 'test2',
    third: 'test'
}];
var options = [];
$.each(studentselectValues, function () {
    options.push('<option value="' + this.key + '">' + this.value + ' ' + this.third + '</option>');
});
var optionsS = options.join();
$('select[name="cf_Student"]').append(optionsS);
```